# BB10 Cascades: expand/collapse items in ListView

Tags: listview, qml, expand, listitem, blackberry-cascades

I'm looking for code sample to collapse/expand `ListItem` in QML.

Currently I have an idea to do it through toggling `visible` flag for each child of triggered item. But I can't imagine how to iterate the children. Here is piece of code:

```
        ListView {
            dataModel: XmlDataModel {...}
            onTriggered: {
                var dataType = dataModel.itemType(indexPath)
                if (dataType == "header")
                {
                    var childrenCount = dataModel.childCount(indexPath);
                    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
                    {
                        // what to write here to get each child ListItem?
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: [There is a sample](http://blackberry.github.io/Cascades-Samples/filtereddatamodel.html) for my task where we inherit from `bb::cascades::DataModel` and override `childCount`. But I would like to not deal with C++ classes.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could consider setting a visible property in the `dataModel` and binding the visibility of the children to it.

```
ListView {
    dataModel: XmlDataModel {...}
...
    listItemComponents: [
        ListItemComponent {
            visible: ListItemData.visible
...
        }
    ]
}
```

Then to loop through the children and make them all invisible you could just loop through the `dataModel`.

Comment: Yes, it can be an approach. Little disadvantage that we need to keep visual property in model structure. I'll wait for possible answer showing how to iterate `ListItem` children.

Comment: This has come up before around SO. I don't believe you can iterate through ListView children/

Comment: In this case it would be nicer to map `visible` property of each child  to `expanded` property of its parent. Can we access parent in `ListItemData `?

Comment: If you are asking about binding listItemComponents to properties of their parent list view see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375182/accessing-listitemcomponents-on-the-run)

Comment: In my case parent is also `ListItemComponent` and I would like to bind it's property to children's `visible` flag. Still can't find how to access the parent list item.